# stuck with phptime function

Tags: php

What i am trying to achive is return something like this.

day1
day2
day3
...
day7
Today, as in today's date should be equal to day1, tomorrow, should be equal to day 2 and the same applies until day7.

What i have written so far is this but i am stuck and not sure how to proceed.

```
function future_date (){ 
    $numDays=7; 
    for($i=0; $i<$numDays; $i++) { 
        $futuredate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('+' . strval($i) . ' days'));
        print $futuredate;
        return $futuredate;
     }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work with your current code?

Comment: at the moment, the code returns the next 7days in this format, 27-04-2011, but i would like to be day1 as opposed to that.

Comment: Do you mean `for ($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++) echo "day$i\n"`?

Comment: add checks..if i==0 return it as today and if i==1 return as tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I gather your requirements based on your comment, you just need to format the date differently.  That means you need to change the `'d-m-Y'` string.  Take a look at [`date()`](http://php.net/date).

The day of the week can be represented by a lowercase L `date('l')`.